# Notification sound never stop when connected to a bluetooth device - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, notifications, alarm

I'm developing an alarm app which is displaying a notification to the user in a certain time with a long notification sound.

The problem is notification doesn’t stop if I’m connecting bluetooth headphone to the phone, even if I dismissed the notification and even if I killed the app.

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
        .setContentTitle(alarm.getNotificationTitle(context))
        .setContentText(alarm.getNotificationDescription(context))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
        .setForegroundServiceBehavior(NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the notification sound from being played in the bluetooh device?

Comment: .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM) did you try to change this section?